# What is "~" represent in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am not a JavaScript expert, but I'm reading the code and found out that there's a statement like this.

```
if(!~dssClass.indexOf("hideDiv")
```

What's the "~" mean in this statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's bitwise `NOT`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

"take the result of the indexOf lookup, bitwise invert it, then take the logical NOT of that"

Comment: Please note this question is a duplicate and should be deleted

Comment: @JanDvorak - Duplicate questions and answers shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 not all duplicates are created equal. If all they do is copy some other question, keyword for keyword, and only accumulate worse answers than the original had, they are useless. If they ask the same question as the original in a different way, then sure, go ahead, keep it. They might be useful for googlers.